# How to connect with client certificate using a WebView in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, macos, webkit, client-certificates

I am trying to connect to a server that requires a client certificate.
So the normal flow of events that happens when browsing to this server is that the web browser (both Safari and Chrome) prompts the user to select a certificate and retry the operation.

So how can I accomplish this in a embedded WebView in a Cocoa project?
I have so far identified that the error is raised in the `didFailProvisionalLoadWithError` method:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender didFailProvisionalLoadWithError:(NSError *)error forFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    NSLog(@"webView:didFailProvisionalLoadWithError:forFrame:");
    NSLog(@"    error = %@", error);
}
```

The error is indeed `error = Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1206 UserInfo=0x1006a8030 "The server “myserver.xxx” requires a client certificate.`
But how can I display a dialog so that the user can select a certificate from the keychain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

A (known) issue with the WebView component was the culprit.
Opened up a DTS support ticket with Apple and got a workaround.

EDIT:
Here's the workaround from DTS ( I have no idea if this is still valid, since it was 3 years ago):

> Magnus OK, I've had a chance to look at this and I know what's going
>   on.  Before we start talking about WebView, I need to bring you up to
>   speed on the delegate methods used by NSURLConnection, which is the
>   underlying API used to actually load data off the 'net. 
>   NSURLConnection started out supporting a single authentication
>   delegate callback, -connection:didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:, to
>   which it passed the various authentication challenges that were
>   supported at that time (username/password-style challenges).  In Mac
>   OS X 10.6 (and iOS 3.0) NSURLConnection was enhanced to support two
>   addition types of authentication challenges for TLS connections: o
>   client identity challenges
>   (NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate), giving the delegate the
>   opportunity to select a client identity for a given TLS connection o
>   server trust challenges (NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust), giving
>   the delegate the opportunity to override the server trust evaluation
>   for a given TLS connection For compatibility reasons it was not
>   possible to pass these challenges to the delegate under all
>   circumstances, so NSURLConnection introduced a new delegate callback,
>   -connection:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:, that allows the delegate to opt in to these challenges.
>                       *                   *                   * Now, let's bring this back to your app.  As I mentioned, WebView uses
>   NSURLConnection and, for each connection, acts as the connection
>   delegate.  It intercepts authentication challenges and passes them to
>   its resource load delegate.  This works just fine for old school
>   authentication challenges, because WebView gets the challenge without
>   having to do anything special; but it fails for TLS connection
>   authentication challenges, because the delegate has to opt in those
>   challenges. What you really need is the WebView version of the
>   'canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace' authentication challenge. 
>   Well, it turns out that this is actually implemented.  In looking
>   through the open source for WebView, I found that there's a private
>   delegate callback,
>   -webView:resource:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:forDataSource:,
>   that does exactly what you want.
>   http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/WebKit/WebKit-7533.20.25/mac/WebView/WebResourceLoadDelegatePrivate.h
>   If you implement that method you can opt in to the client identity
>   authentication challenge and, based on that challenge, present a user
>   interface that allows the user to select an identity.  I prototyped
>   this in your test app and it works a charm.  Here's the code I used to
>   get the client identity challenge:
>   - (BOOL)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace
>   *)protectionSpace forDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource {
>        NSLog(@"%@", [protectionSpace authenticationMethod]);
>        return [[protectionSpace authenticationMethod] isEqual:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate]; } and here's the
>   code I used to respond to it:
>   - (void)webView:(WebView *)sender resource:(id)identifier didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge
>   *)challenge fromDataSource:(WebDataSource *)dataSource {
>        NSLog(@"didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge");
>        NSString *authenticationMethod = [[challenge protectionSpace] authenticationMethod];
>        NSLog(@"    authenticationMethod = %@", authenticationMethod);
>
> ```
>  [[challenge sender] continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge]; }
> ```
>
> Obviously in a real app you'd need to display some UI and then, once
>   the user has selected a client identity, create a credential for it
>   (+[NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:certificates:persistence:])
>   and then apply that credential to the chalenge
>   (-useCredential:forAuthenticationChallenge:).
>                       *                   *                   * So where do you proceed from here?  Regardless of what else you do, you should
>   file a bug against WebView to get the
>   -webView:resource:canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:forDataSource: delegate callback published in the public headers.  It's an obvious,
>   and most annoying, omission. http://developer.apple.com/bugreporter/
>   Once you've filed a bug, please send me the bug number so that I can
>   associate it with this incident. Beyond that, the way forward is less
>   clear.  If you're creating a non-Mac App Store app, my recommendation
>   would be that you just implement the
>   'canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace' delegate callback as I've
>   shown above and move on with your life.  OTOH, if you're creating a
>   Mac App Store app, where the use of private API, including delegate
>   callbacks, is strictly prohibited, life gets a lot trickier.  Let me
>   know in that case and we can discuss your options. Share and Enjoy

Comment: Uhmm.. Care to say what is the issue itself, and what the workaround was...?

Answer (score 1):

Set a `WebResourceLoadDelegate` and implement the authentication-challenge–related delegate methods. You will be prompted when an authentication challenge is received, at which time you can provide the certificate to use.

***ETA:*** Here is how you can create an `NSURLCredential` from a certificate stored in `clientSide.p12`:

```
NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
        pathForResource:@"clientside" ofType:@"p12"];
NSData *PKCS12Data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
CFDataRef inPKCS12Data = (CFDataRef)PKCS12Data;    
SecIdentityRef identity;
SecTrustRef trust;
extractIdentityAndTrust(inPKCS12Data, &identity, &trust);

SecCertificateRef certificate = NULL;
SecIdentityCopyCertificate (identity, &certificate); 

const void *certs[] = {certificate};
CFArrayRef certArray = CFArrayCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, certs, 1, NULL);

NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential
        credentialWithIdentity:identity
        certificates:(NSArray*)certArray
        persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];
```

This comes from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164846/nsurlcredentialstorage-and-client-certificate-authentication). You might also find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460626/iphone-https-client-cert-authentication) helpful. I found these by Googling for "nsurlcredential certificate".

Comment: Thanks, could you point me to a sample or provide some (pseudo) code?

Comment: Sample: [TwitterStreamViewController](https://github.com/danielctull/json-framework/blob/1e4278a957c4df7ecddf412c70db38b98a5ed9d2/Examples/TwitterStream/Classes/TwitterStreamViewController.m#L50) Another approach might be to set the credential before the request is made. This is used with HTTP-Auth by the Cappucino NativeHost in [AppController+WebResourceLoadDelegate.m](https://github.com/280north/cappuccino/blob/master/Tools/NativeHost/AppController%2BWebResourceLoadDelegate.m).

Comment: But these examples are using basich auth with username/pwd. How can I select a certificate from the keychain and pass on with the request?

Comment: I just edited my answer to provide some sample code for using a certificate stored in a file.

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help. But I haven't yet figured out on how to get the certificate from the keychain. Your code example uses a file, but I need the certificate from the keychain (as stated in the question, since it's from a Smart Card). Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: You should really open a second question about the keychain. It's a separate subject. Your question about how to connect using a client certificate has been answered; your next question is about how to *get* that client certificate. :)

Comment: Well, that's one way of earning only half of the bounty :) Please read my question again. I don't see on how "select a certificate from the keychain" could be interpreted as file only and exclude Smart Cards.