# How to let AVPlayer retrieve playlist secured by SSL?

Tags: ios, ipad, ssl, avplayer, http-live-streaming

We´re developing a HTTP-streaming iOS app that requires us to receive playlists from a secured site. This site requires us to authenticate using a self signed SSL certificate.

We read the credentials from a .p12 file before we use NSURLConnection with a delegate to react to the authorization challenge.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:  self.credentials forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace
{
    return YES;
}
```

By doing this initial connection to the URL where we´re getting the .m3u8 playlist we´re able to play back the playlist using AVPlayer. The problem is that this method only works in the simulator.

NOTE: We´re able to download the playlist using the NSURLConnection on device. This must mean that the AVPlayer somehow can´t continue using the trust established during this initial connection.

We have also tried adding the credentials to the [NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] without any luck.

Below follows our shotgun approach for that:

```
NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                         initWithHost:host
                                         port:443
                                         protocol:@"https"
                                         realm:nil
                                         authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate];



[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:creds
                                                    forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace];

    NSURLProtectionSpace *protectionSpace2 = [[NSURLProtectionSpace alloc]
                                         initWithHost:host
                                         port:443
                                         protocol:@"https"
                                         realm:nil
                                         authenticationMethod:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];



[[NSURLCredentialStorage sharedCredentialStorage] setDefaultCredential:creds
                                                    forProtectionSpace:protectionSpace2];
```

EDIT: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164846/nsurlcredentialstorage-and-client-certificate-authentication): the above method doesn´t work with certificates.

Any hint to why it doesn´t work on device, or an alternate solution is welcome!

Comment: According to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164846/nsurlcredentialstorage-and-client-certificate-authentication NSURLCredentialStorage doesn´t work for certificates. I guess that´s still the case then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From iOS 6 onwards AVAssetResourceLoader can be used for retrieving an HTTPS secured playlist or key file.

> An AVAssetResourceLoader object mediates resource requests from an AVURLAsset object with a delegate object that you provide. When a request arrives, the resource loader asks your delegate if it is able to handle the request and reports the results back to the asset.

Please find the sample code below.

```
// AVURLAsset + Loader
AVURLAsset      *asset          = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem    *playerItem     = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
AVAssetResourceLoader *loader   = asset.resourceLoader;
[loader setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];

// AVPlayer
AVPlayer        *avPlayer       = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
```

You will need to handle the  resourceLoader:shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:delegate method which will be called when there is an authentication need and you can use NSURLConnection to request for the secured resource.

```
(BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader    shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest
{

 //Handle NSURLConnection to the SSL secured resource here
  return YES;
}
```

Hope this helps!

P.S : The proxy approach using CocoaHTTPServer works well but using an AVAssetResourceLoader is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for this update! I've long since moved on to different pastures, but this is very useful for everyone else.

Comment: Does it get called if you use 'https' scheme?

Comment: @Timur - yes, it does. Wouldn't be a lot of use for encryption keys and stuff otherwise!

Answer (score 6):

It seems that until Apple lets us control what NSURLConnections the AVPlayer uses the only answer seems to be to implement a HTTP loopback server.

To quote the apple representative that answered our support question:

> Another option is to implement a loopback
>   HTTP server and point client objects at that.  The clients can use
>   HTTP (because their requests never make it off the device), while the
>   loopback HTTP server itself can use HTTPS to connect to the origin
>   server.  Again, this gives you access to the underlying
>   NSURLConnections, allowing you to do custom server trust evaluation.
>
> Using this technique with UIWebView is going to be tricky unless you
>   completely control the content at the origin server.  If the origin
>   server can return arbitrary content, you have to grovel through the
>   returned HTTP and rewrite all the links, which is not much fun.  A
>   similar restriction applies to MPMoviePlayerController/AVPlayer, but
>   in this case it's much more common to control all of the content and
>   thus be able to avoid non-relative links.

EDIT:
I managed to implement a loopback server using custom implemenations of the 
HTTPResponse and HTTPConnection classes found in [CocoaHTTPServer](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer)

I can´t disclose the source, but I used NSURLConnection together with a mix of the AsyncHTTPResponse and DataHTTPResponse demonstration responses.

EDIT:
Remember to set `myHttpServerObject.interface = @"loopback";`

EDIT: WARNING!!! This approach does not seem to work with airplay since the airplay device will ask 127.1.1.1 for encryption keys. The correct approach seems to be defined here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EncryptionandAuthentication/EncryptionandAuthentication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011045-CH5-SW1

"Specify the keys in the .m3u8 files using an application-defined URL scheme."

EDIT: 
**An apple TV and iOS update has resolved the issue mentioned in the edit above!**

Comment: I'm trying to mimic your technique and I've hit a wall.  How did you secure the traffic between your local server and your app?  With HTTP and a jailbroken iOS device, it's trivial to capture the traffic with tcpdump.  To use HTTPS, you need a certificate that AVPlayer will accept (it must be issued by one of the device's root certificate authorities).

Comment: We didn´t secure the traffic between the local server and the app. The customer we´re developing this app for are well aware that a dedicated hacker could break the security. That´s why they´re upgrading to a third party media player vendor in the future.

Comment: 'It seems that until Apple lets us control what NSURLConnections the AVPlayer uses the only answer seems to be to implement a HTTP loopback server.' is this still true for iOS5?

Comment: Yeah, I think so. That is how many DRM libraries work. I haven't updated myself on new video capabilities in iOS6 and 7 though.

Comment: Is above still accurate? Shouldn't now 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' in .plist handle authentication to server with self-signed certificates?