# How to get Airplay working with encrypted HTTPS streaming?

Tags: ios, encryption, avplayer, airplay

I´ve been struggling to get AirPlay to work with encrypted streams playing in AVPlayer.

Reading [this page by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AirPlayGuide/EncryptionandAuthentication/EncryptionandAuthentication.html) doesn´t do me much good.

> Serve keys from a protected HTTPS realm. Before playback begins, your
>   app can use NSURLConnection to authenticate itself, providing
>   credentials that are kept hidden.

**I could only get this to work in the simulator. Not on the device.**

> Use cookies over HTTPS. Your app can make a connection to an HTTPS
>   server and authenticate the application in an application-defined way.
>   Your server can then issue a cookie that applies to the key URLs. You
>   should set the cookie to expire long after playback is complete. The
>   server must then require the presence of a valid session cookie in
>   future GET requests for the keys.
>   For maximum reliability, if the expiration date is in the near future, the server should 
>   update the cookie’s expiration date in its response to future GET requests.

**Haven´t actually tried this since I don´t have direct access to the server setup, but I am going to if no other answers appear.**

> Specify the keys in the .m3u8 files using an application-defined URL
>   scheme. The app should register a custom NSURLProtocol to handle
>   requests for those URLs. The player then calls back into your app when
>   it needs to load a key URL; your app can then obtain the key using a
>   secure side channel and can provide it to the player.

**This doesn´t seem to work because AVPlayer HTTP connections bypass the NSURLProtocol system completely. You just can´t intercept any of the HTTP requests made by the AVPlayer.**

I would be eternally grateful if anyone has a way of solving the encryption key serving problem in a manner that works with AVPlayer and AirPlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the trouble I was wrestling with went away with the iOS 5.1.1 update and the following Apple TV update. The iOS 5.1.1 update was not enough to fix the issue on it´s own, but together with the subsequent Apple TV update all is fine and dandy once again.

It is now enough to implement your own loopback server as I have described in an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000614/how-to-let-avplayer-retrieve-playlist-secured-by-ssl/).

Comment: Can you airplay encrypted hls m3u8 using apple tv 3th generation and ios 8.1?

Comment: Sadly, I haven't worked on apps using video playback in 3 years. I haven't kept up with development. Sorry!