# How can MPMoviePlayerController play localhost URL?

Tags: ios, url, localhost, mpmovieplayercontroller, drm

I'm using Widevine to deal with DRM movies. After `WV_Initialize` and `WV_Play`, I get a responseURL that is "**`http://127.0.0.1:20001/movie.m3u8`**"

I then pass it to `MPMoviePlayerController`

```
self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:responseURL];
self.playerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
self.playerController.shouldAutoplay = YES;
[self.playerController prepareToPlay];
[self.playerController play];
```

And the movie **is played**. What is happening here? How can `MPMoviePlayerController` play localhost URL?

Comment: The quote in this answer provide more clues http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109555/1418457

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widevine actually opens a local media proxy on you machine. it connects on one hand to the "real" video server, takes the media and - after decrypting and doing other stuff - procides it for you on your 127.0.0.1:PORT via RTMP/http.